# nodemail / gmail / xoauth2 - Error: connect ETIMEDOUT

Tags: timeout, gmail, nodemailer

I have a node express application that I am attempting to add nodemail support.  I have created a gmail account for this purpose (NOTE: the gmail account has "Less Secure App" enabled).  My code is as follows:

```
var mailOptions = {
  from: "XXXX@gmail.com",
  to: YYYY@gmail.com,
  subject: "Test",
  generateTextFromHTML: true,
  text: 'This is a test'
};

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    xoauth2: xoauth2.createXOAuth2Generator({
      user: 'XXXX@gmail.com', // Your gmail address.
      clientId: '123456789abcd-123456789abcdef.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      clientSecret: 'XXXX-123456789',
      refreshToken: '1/abcdefg',
      accessToken: '123.abcdef'
    })
  }
});

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response) {
  if (error) {
    console.log('BAD' + error);
  } else {
    console.log('GOOD' + response);
  }
  transporter.close();
});
```

I am able to send e-mail some of the time.  After a few successful attempts, I get the following error:

**Error: connect ETIMEDOUT**

I will continue to get these timeout errors and then it will work again for a few attempts.

Comment: I did notice that if I restart my node application, I get one to two good e-mail sends before I get the timeout (never more than two good e-mail sends).

Comment: Just a little more information.  I greatly simplified my node express application to on a post() send out an e-mail as outlined in the above code.  I also commented out the transporter.close() call shown above since looking at the documentation I probably don't need to call it.  I launched my node express app and was able to get four e-mails sent before the time-out occurred (sent the four e-mails within a minute of each other).  After the timeout occurred, I restarted my node expression application and the timeout occurs right away.